# Does SAP HANA gradually phase out SAP BI

Tags: hana, sap-bw

1. Can HANA store all the data carried by SAP BI in HANA "in-memory"?
2. Are there certain BI tools that are available only in SAP BI and not possible in SAP HANA due to architectural differences in nature of Data warehouse and Database tools now and in future? If yes, what are those?
3. How does a SAP BI developer use HANA? Does he write HANA SQL Scripts on SAP BI along with ABAP code for BI customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ad 1) Yes it can, but it doesn't have to (dynamic tiering and memory displacement can be used).

ad 2) Datawarehouses and DBMS are two different things, so there are lots of differences. If your question is more directed at whether or not SAP HANA can and will replace SAP BW anytime soon, I recommend the following blog posts:

- https://blogs.saphana.com/2012/06/13/does-sap-hana-replace-bw-hint-no/
- https://blogs.saphana.com/2012/06/20/does-sap-hana-replace-bw-hint-no-part-2/
- https://blogs.saphana.com/2014/04/17/does-sap-hana-replace-bw-hint-still-no/
- https://blogs.saphana.com/2015/07/06/sap-hana-replace-bw-hint-no/

ad 3) Yes, that's the case. For example expert routines can often be scripted in SQLScript, thereby avoiding data transfer between HANA server and SAP BW application server.

Comment: This is a great discussion. The takeaway is: It's still being debated. A lot of reports done through BW are being done through S/4 HANA at the database layer. However, BW is still needed as it accomplishes a lots of Extractions from different sources, complex transformations, etc.. that haven't been moved over to HANA. As rightly said, moving over to HANA completely is a project in itself. Hope i am heading right.

Answer (score 0):

> Can HANA store all the data carried by SAP BI in HANA "in-memory"?

Yes it can store all the data carried by SAP BI. Normally BI will have two databases, the first database is installed by default during the installation (that might be any database e.g DB2, MS SQL Server. If you want to keep the data as HANA you have to manually select it and HANA DB has to be physically installed). This will be used for auditing or running the BI System.

Whereas the other database or second database is where the actual data resides, where we are required to do reporting in BI by taking the database as a source.

> Are there certain BI tools that are available only in SAP BI and not possible in SAP HANA due to architectural differences in nature of Datawarehouse and Database tools now and in future? If yes, what are those?

HANA is actually a database, whereas BI is a few reporting tools with various flavours such as webi, crystal.
A connector is required to connect between BI and HANA, if we want to connect only the HANA DB with other tools (you can connect ones such as MS Excel).

> How does a SAP BI developer use HANA? Does he write HANA Sql Scripts on SAP BI along with ABAP code for BI customization?

A BI Developer will only use the BI tool and all the features which are there in the BI reporting tool, whereas writing SQL Scripts and HANA ABAP code can be written at a backend database level depending upon the requirements by a consultant called HANA Developer, whose responsibility it is to build models at the backend level and make them available to integrate with BI and allow the HANA model to pull in the BI Reporting tool for reporting purposes.